# Can we develop windows 8 or windows 10 mobile application using visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, windows-mobile

My requirement is simple **Can we develop windows 8 or windows 10 mobile application using visual studio 2010 ?**

Is there any work around. If not can anyone help me suggest best version for VS to develop mobile apps on windows version.

Comment: Do you mean "Windows Store Apps" ? I believe that's what they are called today. Note that classic Win32 applications still work.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention let me rephrase it **Can we develop windows 8 or windows 10 mobile application using visual studio 2010 ?**

Answer (score 0):

[**Getting started developing apps for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714071(v=vs.105).aspx)

To start developing your apps, you'll need to install the right tools to get the job done. The Visual Studio 2012 family of development tools offers a powerful development environment to build great apps quickly. Two free versions of Visual Studio 2012 are available to build your apps for Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you must have Visual Studio 2015 for developing Windows 10 mobile apps.
you can also develop windows 8 app in visual studio 2015.

[Download Latest Version](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads)